# Heroku: Python Flask app - automatically redirecting from https to http

Tags: ssl, heroku, https, flask, http-status-code-301

I'm writing an app for Facebook, which needs to be secure. The initial page, https://myapp.com, loads perfectly fine.

However when I click a link to https://myapp.com/link, Chrome complains that the app is trying to load from an insecure source. I get the following message in the console:

"[blocked] The page at 'https://www.facebook.com/page/app_###' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://myapp.com/link/': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS."

Now the link is an absolute URL with the https prefix, yet apparently the page is trying to load from the http version.

I visited the domain itself and checked the Network tab in the Chrome console to see what was happening. The following happens:

1. The GET to https://myapp.com/link is a 301, moved permanently.
2. This then redirects to http://myapp.com/link

As far as I can tell, there is nothing in my python code to make this happen, so I suspect  some feature of Heroku is causing this, but I haven't been able to find anyone else with this problem.

As a side note, I used Flask-SSLify to add a redirect back to the https version. This redirect works, but Chrome still blocks the page because it passes through the insecure version.

Answer (score 3):

I feel so stupid for working this out five minutes after posting the question, but it is a little obscure.

It turns out the problem was that the page I was attempting to reach was "https://myapp.com/link/" with the trailing slash.

"https://myapp.com/link" redirects to "http://myapp.com/link/".

I don't know why the protocol isn't preserved by this redirect, it may be either Flask or Heroku, though I suspect it is Flask. Regardless it seems like a bug.

Hope this winds up helping somebody else.